# Can we have multiple Grpc services in the Grpc server for the same Protobuf file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, grpc

I have an `ASP.NET Core 6 Web Api` application.

I have a `Grpc Client` and a `Grpc Server`.

I have a proto file:

```
service FooService {
   rpc GetFirstData (FirstRequest) returns (FirstResult);
   rpc GetAnotherData (AnotherRequest) returns (AnotherResult);
}
```

In the `Grpc Client` I have 2 services which take `FooClient` as a parameter. The first service sends `GetFirstData  request` and the second Service sends `GetAnotherData request` to the `Grpc Server`. There are no issues here.

With the server, however, if I try to add 2 services, I get a Server Error 500.

```
public class FirstServerService : Protos.FooService.FooServiceBase
{
    public override Task<FirstResult> GetFirstData (FirstRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
    }
}

public class AnotherServerService : Protos.FooService.FooServiceBase
{
    public override Task<AnotherResult> GetAnotherData (AnotherRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

**The question is:** Is it possible to have multiple services on the backend implementing methods from the same Proto file?

Comment: Lol I was just looking for the answer and you asked it 6 hours ago. Exactly what I'd like to achieve and group them somehow so they have different endpoints for gRPC Web like /impl1/FooService and /impl2/FooService

Comment: Maybe using `RequireHost` and listening on different ports for each implementation e.g. FirstService listens on 5500 and the other on 5501... would work...

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/110

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14900

Comment: The only way to possibly achieve this would be some sort of custom server implementation I think. Either listen on different ports like Konrad said, or map the endpoints manually. As soon as you register them with *MapGrpcService* you essentially register the same service base twice on the same endpoint, which causes the error

Answer (score 0):

In the Grpc Client you must have two server endpoints defined in appsettins.json or hardcoded as parameters when adding client services in dependency injection in  Program.cs such as:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFirstClient>(p => new FirstClient(builder.Configuration["GrpcServerUrl1"]));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISecondClient>(p => new SecondClient(builder.Configuration["GrpcServerUrl2"]));
```

now each client service in your Grpc Client program will be reached to different grpc server.